# NodeManager failed to start because of unmappable characters like «p.ermakov»

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

When I start NodeManager I see this error in log. This job always start when server start, how to remove this job and resolve the issue?

```
Application application_1511362704902_0007 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1511362704902_0007_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000

    For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: 
    http://hdp-namenode.vk-dev6.dev.ru:8088/cluster/app/application_1511362704902_0007
    Then click on links to logs of each attempt.

    Diagnostics: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters: 
    /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/«p.ermakov»/appcache/application_1511362704902_0007
    Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

Comment: Remove those Cyrillic characters from your linux username

Comment: I remove problem path and hdfs user «p.ermakov». Remove /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/?p.ermakov? and restart yarn.
But, application application_1511362704902_0007 start again when NodeManager start. I down know how to prevent application from launch. If do this i think i can remove path and problem will be salved.

Comment: You can kill old applications from the YARN UI or command line

Comment: Application already dead and marked as failed on history server.

Answer (score 0):

What i do:
stop all yarn services

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r -f /home/?p.ermakov?
hdfs dfs -rm -r -f /spark-history/*
hdfs dfs -rm -r -f /spark2-history/*
rm -rf /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/
rm -rf /hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/
```

and start all yarn services.
This resolve issue for me.